# How to force evaluate?

Tags: clojure

After playing a while with quote/unquote, I wanted to do a trick, but it didn't want to be done. Here's what I did and what come out :

```
user=> (let [x '#(inc 1)] `(1 ~x))
(1 (fn* [] (inc 1)))
```

But what I wanted was :

```
(1 2)
```

Can you help me do that ? :)

And also explain what "part" of Clojure you are using...

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: It does unquote what was quoted (a function). Just as the above shows. Now, how can you invoke a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

```
user=> (let [x `(inc 1)] 
         (eval `(list 1 ~x)))
(1 2)
```

Or more conventionally:

```
user=> (defmacro foo [x] 
        `(list 1 ~x))
#'user/foo
user=> (foo (inc 1))
(1 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work like you want it to:

```
user> (let [x (#(inc 1))] `(1 ~x))
;=> (1 2)
```

Comment: i could just have done this :  (let [x (inc 1)] `(1 ~x)), which would mean just evaluate the function before putting it into x. nevertheless, thanks for your idea